# What is the meaning of external work in electric potential?

Tags: potential, work, potential-energy, voltage, conventions

We learned that  $$-Work = \Delta U = q(Va-Vb).$$ However, we write that $$W = q(Va-Vb)$$ in this question. *Why don't we write the minus sign in the equation?* *How does external work affect the minus sign ?* Can you help me to understand these questions and explain them clearly? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the potential energy function is introduced, it is because
the work is being done by a conservative-force...
in this case, the electrostatic force.

Thus, "Work" in "**-Work = delta U**" refers to the **work done by the electrostatic force**.

- Why the minus sign?
  From the work-energy theorem, the work-done is separated into parts that
  "don't depend on the path" (that's the work done by conservative forces) and those that "do depend on the path" (that's the work done by nonconservative forces)
  \begin{align}
  W_{net}&=\Delta K\\
  W_{cons}+W_{noncons}&=\Delta K\\
  \end{align}
  We introduce an "energy of position" (energy of configuration) called the potential energy.  We choose to express this as $W_{cons}=-\Delta U$ so that we can write
  \begin{align}
  W_{net}&=\Delta K\\
  W_{noncons}&=\Delta K - (-\Delta U) = \Delta (K+U)
  \end{align}
  and refer to the $(K+U)$ are the "total mechanical energy".
  *It would be weird to use "$W_{cons}=+\Delta U$" because "$(K-U)$" doesn't look like a "total".* Thus, we use  $W_{cons}=-\Delta U$.

In the context of your question, "W = q(Va-Vb)" the "work" there refers to an external agent applying forces (to balance the electrostatic force... so that the displacement is done "slowly" in a quasi-equilibrium way... practically speaking, "moved with a tiny constant velocity").

[For clarity, it might be good to specify the initial and final positions.]

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: the opposite sign of the result we find is always the external work to balance the mechanical energy conservation. is not it?

Comment: @llee7-jkonn I have given the logical progression of how the notion of "potential energy" is introduced when one starts with forces. After the introduction of potential energy, then we have a notion of "mechanical energy" (as kinetic+potential). Note that as a charge is displaced from initial to final position, the electric force at each point is determined by Coulomb's law. However, an external agent does not have to apply that same magnitude force.... if it applied a larger force, then the charge would be accelerated. So, the minus-sign here is really about the conservative force.

Answer (score 0):

In the first equation the work is that done by the electric field. In the second equation the work is that done by an external agent. The work done by the electric field is the negative of the work done by the external agent.

The gravity analogy is when I lift an object a height $h$ I, the external (to the object/earth system) agent do positive work (since my force is in the same direction as the displacement of the object) of $mgh$. At the same time the gravitational field does negative work of $-mgh$ (since the direction of its force is opposite the displacement of the object) taking the energy I gave the object and storing it as gravitational potential energy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the  great explanation

Comment: @llee7jkonn I see that you have been back and forth about what answer to accept, mine or robphy, and that's ok because you should always accept the answer that works best for you. But it would be helpful to me if you could tell me why, though you certainly are not obligated to say so.